# "Представляет" в значении "представляет собой"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли слово "представляет" употреблять в качестве "представляет собой"?

Примеры:

1. Эта пьеса представляет програмную миниатюру в романтическом стиле;
2. Полотно представляет образец Высокого Возрождения;
3. Вышереченное войско представляет гвардию императора Карла Великого.

Comment: А вы слышали, чтобы так говорили?

Comment: Да, поэтому и спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

С таким вообще не сталкивался, но словари немного позволяют:
Малый академический словарь:
(**обычно** в сочетании со словами "собой" или "из себя") Быть, являться кем-, чем-л.
В словаре Ожегова и Шведовой есть такое:
Являться, быть. *Книга представляет значительное явление.*

Порой из-за этого может образовываться двусмысленность: *войско представляет гвардию => войско — представитель гвардии*.